# How to show a window with some text when mouse passed over a css class

Tags: html, css

I'm a noob with css and html (and js).
I write an html page, with a table of athletes, each row is rappresented by a css class named "athlete-name", for example:

```
<div id="message-hide" style="display: none"> Hello world! </div>

<td class="athlete-name" style="padding-right: .75rem !important;">
    ElMaestroDeToMare
</td>
```

I want to show a cartoon with some text when I pass over this element. I try to use class hover, but I think that I miss something because it does not work.

here is my css code:

```
    .athlete-name {
        @include set_font($smallfontsize);
        font-weight: $bold;
        color: $font_color;
    }

    .athlete-name:hover + .message-hide {
        display: block;
        color: black;
    }
```

Comment: Do this help you? https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Comment: You will need to use Javascript as the `.message-hide` is not a child of `.athlete-name`  have a look here for a jQuery option https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: @Tartarus w3schools is a poor resource to give out. its content is very old and not refreshed

Comment: @Qpirate It helps us with basic knowledge, not everything like beautiful CSS.

Comment: It doesn't work. I created the css class like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp , but in td container it does not work if I don't use <table> in html https://jsfiddle.net/nsua8ckq/

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something called a "Tooltips", you have some examples here : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp.